# Extjs Loading Icon

Tags: svg, extjs, sencha-touch, loading, extjs4.2

I am looking to get a loading icon as below in Extjs. I came across Extjs loadMask but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Are there any other existing components that I could use and perhaps make changes to, to achieve this behavior and look? If not, any suggestions on how this could be implemented?

[image]

Updates: I am trying to add the icon for every row in a table and below is the code which is included as one of the items in a list under `this.columns`. However, nothing gets displayed on the rows. Am I missing something ?

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    sortable:false,
    menuDisabled:true,
    width:50,
    hidden:false,

    items: [{
      xtype:'component',
      cls:'spinner-circular', 
      height:50

    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We made our own component to display loadicon as following :

[image]

it's just as simple as :

```js
{
        xtype: 'component',
        cls: 'spinner-circular',
        height: 50
    }
```

with css being :

```css
@keyframes spinner-circular {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.spinner-circular:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #f48b31;
  animation: spinner-circular .6s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: I am looking to add this loading icon to every row in a table.  But for some reason, the icon just doesn't display at all. Any ideas on why this might be the case?